# Repeating code works for a certain amount of time and then breaks

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, discord.py, global-variables

I've made a simple discord bot with Python that tracks how long people are in a specific set of channels for one hour every day. Essentially, it's an attendance tracker for my gaming group that has an event for an hour every day. I've been having an issue where it works perfectly fine for a time, and then breaks. It doesn't crash, it just repeats the attendance from the previous day over and over again. I have it running on a server, and sometimes restarting the server works, and other times it doesn't. From my logs I know that everything seems to work fine right up to the point at which it adds new data to my dictionary that's the base data structure of the whole thing. For some reason, it just seems to randomly quit putting in new information, and I have no idea why. The code uses async functions and global variables, which I'm inexperienced with, so I'm thinking something there could be an issue.

This probably isn't a lot to go on, but I'm relatively inexperienced, so maybe there's something obvious I'm missing. Any help is appreciated!

Attempted fixes:

Restarting server code is hosted on

Adding log messages to pinpoint state of my data structure at key points

Results:

Restarting seems to help sometimes, but the issue repeats later.

The relevant function:

```py
#Loop for attendance tracking during hour
@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def attendancePoints(): #Global variables instantiated in seperate function on bot startup
    global eventChannels #Channels to be checked
    global server #Discord server to run on
    global mems #Dictionary of members - Key = name, value = total attendance time
    global count # Counter to stop loop after sixty minutes
    final_msg = ""
    count += 1
    print("Attendance " + str(count))#log
    
#Loop that adds members and attendance time to mems
    for channel in eventChannels:
        for mem in channel.members:
            mems[mem.display_name] = mems.get(mem.display_name, 0) + 1
#If the loop has run for an hour, break it and output attendance
    if count == 60:
        est = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")#log
        time = dt.datetime.now(est)#log
        f = open("outLog.txt", "a")#log
        f.write("Attendance before wipe on " + time.strftime('%a %d %b %Y, %I:%M%p') + "\n\n")#log
        f.write("Raw Dict: \n" + pp.pformat(mems))#log
        final_msg = attStrConstructor2(mems)
        f.write("\n\nMessage string: \n" + final_msg)#log
        await server.get_channel(00000000000000).send(final_msg) #change channel number here
        print("Attendance Submitted")
        count = 0
        mems = dict()
        f.write("\n\nPost wipe raw dict: \n\n" + pp.pformat(mems) + "\n\n -----------------------\n\n")
        f.close()
        attendancePoints.stop()
```

Comment: On a sidenote, you might want to learn about logging module, you're now mixing writing to files, printing etc

Comment: Are you seeing the `Attendance Submitted` message? If so, I can't see how it wouldn't do `mems = dict()` to clear out the previous day's attendance.

Comment: And what does it say in the log file when it writes `Post wipe raw dict`?

Comment: Please provide the logs you are generating in this function as well, so that the community can better assist you

Comment: @alko I just learned about that today, actually, so I'll try and integrate that at some point.

Comment: @Barmar I do get the message, which is why I'm so confused. Everything I see indicates it should work. My log file says that the dictionary is wiped, and still clean at the beginning of the next day.

Comment: Is it possible that the issue is storing my data in RAM instead of permeant memory? I'm running the code on a server with only about 500mb of RAM, but that seems like it should be more than enough to hold a dictionary of minimal size.

Comment: The amount of physical RAM is irrelevant unless it's a microcontroller. Real computers use virtual memory.